# Scala Iterator next called after size does not raise error

Tags: scala, iterator

Using local interpreter of Scala 2.13.10 I am running the following code

```
scala> val it = Iterator("a", "number", "of", "words")
val it: Iterator[String] = <iterator>
scala> it.size
val res0: Int = 4
scala> it.next()
val res14: String = a
```

I was under the assumption that running the command it.size will traverse the iterator, and it.next() will fail, as it noted in the Scala documentation

> it.size   The number of elements returned by it. Note: it will be at its end after this operation!

https://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/collections-2.13/iterators.html

What I am missing here?

Comment: So what the spec of `Iterator` says is that after calling any method other than `hasNext` or `next` the `Iterator` is left in an unspecified state where it may work, not work at all, work wrongly, throw exceptions, launch missiles or whatever, That it worked today is not proof that it will work tomorrow.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The overview doesn't fully describe the behavior of `size`.  For iterators where `knownSize` is nonnegative (as in those created from a finite collection), `size` does not in fact traverse the iterator.

That said, `size` is one of the methods on `Iterator` where the only safe thing to do after calling it is to not use the iterator again (nearly every method on `Iterator` that's not `hasNext` or `next` is such a method).